# R Time series line chart

Tags: r

I would like a record of coffee dispenses a line chart from the beginning of the recording to the end.  I would like to determine the beverages purchased per day. The respective number per day should be displayed over the complete time span.
After I read in the data set I had first problems with the Date/Time format.
I suspect that I do not bring them into the correct format.

Then I tried to calculate the coffee consumption per day. Then I found out that with my formula it always uses the year 2020, although it goes back to 2019.

So my plot looks quite funny, and there is no year to be found.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks a lot!

Link to the Dataset: https://github.com/Skruff80/Getting-started/blob/master/ProductList.csv

```
coffeedata <- fread("C:/temp/ProductList.csv")

str(coffeedata)
head(coffeedata)
coffeedata$Date = as.Date(coffeedata$Date, "%d.%m.%y")
head(coffeedata)

countcoffee <- function(timeStamps) {
  Dates <- as.Date(strftime(coffeedata$Date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
  allDates <- seq(from = min(Dates), to = max(Dates), by = "day")
  coffee.count <- sapply(allDates, FUN = function(X) sum(Dates == X))
  data.frame(day = allDates, coffee.count = coffee.count)}

daylicounter = countcoffee(df$message.date)

lines(daylicounter)
```

The plot should look something like the picture in the link.
https://github.com/Skruff80/Getting-started/blob/master/example.png

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use ggplot2

You can do that by using the `ggplot2` library, like in this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(daylicounter, aes(day, coffee.count)) +
  geom_line(color = "orange", size = 1) + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

This is the output graph:

[image: Graph]

### Edit

If you need a custom break vector, you can use a code like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
break.vec <- seq(from = min(daylicounter$day), to = max(daylicounter$day),
                   by = "month")

ggplot(daylicounter, aes(day, coffee.count)) +
   geom_line(color = "orange", size = 1) + 
   scale_x_date(breaks = break.vec, date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi  @Louis 

Thanks for your reply! The graph looks good, but the date format on the X-axis is not correct. I think I did something wrong when formatting the time format. The time format should go from 06/01/2019 - 04/04/2010.

Comment: You're welcome @Skruff! If you want a custom breaks, use the code in the edit section :)

Comment: Thanks @Louis, I have used your edited version but the problem with the x-axis remains. If you look at your plot on the x-axis, you see that the start is 2020-04-01 and the end is 2020-10-01. So that means October in 2020, but this is not a forecast :-)

I still suspect that I'm making a mistake when formatting the date.

`coffeedata$Date = as.Date(coffeedata$Date, "%d.%m.%y")`

Answer (score 0):

Could fix the error with the X-axis. As I already suspected, reformatting the date was the error.
I had used

```
%y
```

instead of

```
%Y
```

```
coffeedata$Date = as.Date(coffeedata$Date, "%d.%m.%Y")
```